# Microsoft Edge and Chrome Browsers are throwing an error saying (site name) didn't send any data

Tags: google-chrome, browser, tcp, microsoft-edge, aix

[Here is the Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6WcR.png)

Microsoft Edge and Chrome Browsers are throwing an error saying "(site name) didn't send any data" as in the screen shot? This recreates only when I stay idle for more than 7-8 mins and then click on some other tab on the same page. It is something to do with staying idle on the page. The session timeout is set for 30mins for this site. Please let me know if someone has any idea regarding this?

Comment: There can be many reasons for this error. Try to hard refresh the site by pressing the CTRL+F5 keys. Try to clear the data for the site and again try to visit the site. Try to access the site with HTTP to see whether it works. Try to visit the site in private mode. Check whether the site is not blocked by your proxy server, anti-virus software or VPN. Try to remove the extensions for testing purposes and check the issue again.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT- Thanks for the response, but I am getting this error only when I stay idle for more than 7-8mins,the server is installed on an aix box.

Comment: You can try to check the response status code in the Network tab of developer tools. It may give some hint. I also suggest you to check configuration and settings on a server side.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT - this is what I see in the Network tab of developer tools. (failed) net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Comment: If you are available with an another machine then I suggest try to access the site on the other machine to check whether you can reproduce the similar issue or it can work fine. If it works then issue may be related to the specific machine. If it not work then you may need to check on server side to find the cause of the issue. This approach can help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT - Thanks for the response. Yes, I tried it on different machines but it still didn't work.

Comment: I suggest you to check on your server side. Does other browsers works fine? What kind of site or application it is? Please try to provide mode information about it.